# How do I use tools:overrideLibrary in a build.gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle, android-tv

I'm using the leanback libraries, which require Android 17 or later.  However my app supports a minSDK of 16, so I get a build error from gradle saying

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Tasks:processPhoneDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 17 declared in library /Users/mike/Projects/android-for-dummies-v3/Tasks/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/leanback-v17/21.0.2/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback" to force usage
```

When I look at the [build tools documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:overrideLibrary-marker), I see how to add the `overrideLibrary` marker to my manifest, but the problem is that I'm declaring my minSdk in my gradle file instead of in my manifest.

How do I use `overrideLibrary` when the minSdk is declared in build.gradle instead of in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Dont do this. Instead update minsdkversion in the build.gradle

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to do this, such as conditionally use a library by testing API level before using it.

Comment: For those who don't know what `overrideLibrary` does, "When the lower-priority manifest has a minSdkVersion value that's higher, an error occurs unless you apply the overrideLibrary merge rule." [source](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#merge_conflict_heuristics). Effective, this overrideLibrary simply removes the warning, it does not change anything else.

Answer (score 690, accepted):

Open Android Studio -> Open Manifest File

add 
`<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback"/>` 
 don't forget to include `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` too, before the `<application>` tag

[image]

Comment: in my case `tools:overrideLibrary="info.hoang8f.fbutton"`

Comment: Watch out for included libraries that contain `<uses-sdk tools:ignore="GradleOverrides">`. Those will cause your `tools:overrideLibrary` attribute to be ignored. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062893/android-gradle-manifest-merger-failed

Comment: My problem still exists after adding tools:overrideLibray="ca.barrenechea.widget.recyclerview.decoration". It was working but suddenly stopped working today after creating a new activity.

Comment: @arjunkn : add <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibray="ca.barrenechea.widget.recyclerview.decoration"/> , If its not working check if your tools namespace is correct or not the correct namespace is xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Comment: what if i want more than overridelibrary

Answer (score 229):

it doesn't matter that you declare your minSdk in build.gradle. You have to copy `overrideLibrary` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, as documented [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:overrideLibrary-marker).

```
<manifest 
    ... >
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

The system automatically ignores the sdkVersion declared in AndroidManifest.xml.

I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have to specify any versions in the uses-sdk?  It seems confusing to specify versions in AndroidManifest that are just going to be ignored

Comment: You are right. Is not necessary, anyways if you set it in the AndroidManifest gradle will ignore it at compilation time.

Comment: +1 for display two libs in example. You can't use two seperate uses-sdk tag. so if you want to override two or more you can put comma in-between. Thanks!!

Comment: but this didn't work for me to use two libraries separated by comma, any problem with my library?

Answer (score 20):

```
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ... >
  <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="nl.innovalor.ocr, nl.innovalor.corelib" />
```

I was facing the issue of conflict between different min sdk versions.
 So this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

just changed only android:minSdkVersion="16" and it's work perfect
C:\MyApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

use this code in manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="16"
android:maxSdkVersion="17"
tools:overrideLibrary="x"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `minSdkVersion="7"` in `C:\MyApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\AndroidManifest.xml` and it worked.

Steps:

1. Path: `C:\MyApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Value: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>`
3. Ran command in new cmd prompt:

   `C:\MyApp>phonegap build android --debug
   [phonegap] executing 'cordova build android --debug'...
   [phonegap] completed 'cordova build android --debug'`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is how to use `overrideLibrary` when the minSdk is declared in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

As soulution for all libraries we can match sdk version of them so no unexpected event may happen

```
subprojects { 
afterEvaluate {project -> 
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) { 
        android { 
            compileSdkVersion 28 
            buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
            defaultConfig {
                //It's kinda tricking android studio but anyway it works
                minSdkVersion 17
            }
        } 
    } 
    if (project.hasProperty("dependencies")) {
        dependencies {
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
        }
    }
} 
}
```

Remove libraries that you do not use in your project (gms) and make sure that sdk version matches your app level gradle data

Answer (score 0):

That work for me

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:maxSdkVersion="17"
    tools:overrideLibrary="pl.droidsonroids.gif" />
```

Answer (score -1):

As library requires `minSdkVersion 17` then you can change the same in `build.gradle`(Module:Application) file:

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17 
        targetSdkVersion 25
}
```

and after that building the project should not throw any build error.

Comment: While this would work, it doesn't actually answer the question. OP asks how overrideLibrary is used. And there are specific cases where you'd want to override it instead of comply (as it's fine to override it)