# Android Manifest vs Gradle Script

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I set `minSdkVersion` to be 8 in Gradle build script and `minSdkVersion` to be 4 in Android module manifest.

Which one is taken? Why aren't these 2 synchronized?

Comment: You should set it only in the gradle build file.

Comment: If you set it in `Gradle` its enough. The reason why in `Manifest` its allowed to its probably because of  `overrideLibrary`. For more info refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095077/how-do-i-use-toolsoverridelibrary-in-a-build-gradle-file)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When there was no gradle support in Android, the manifest ruled it all. Now, if you added gradle support to your project, old manifest tags are simply ignored, as gradle [builds your app](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html) and decides which is correct minimum version.

The main reason of this has to be [identified](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html) in this fact:

> These build values override the existing values in the manifest file.
>   This is useful if you want to generate multiple APKs for your modules
>   where each of the apk files has a different application name, minimum
>   SDK version, or target SDK version. When multiple manifests are
>   present, manifest settings are merged in priority of buildType and
>   productFlavor, /main manifest, and the library manifests

In other words, gradle allows *Build variants* and lets you specify min and target SDKs for each.

Comment: @Halim of course not, the manifest still has many definitions for the project like the activities.

Comment: NO! it's safe to remove the  <uses-sdk /> element IF you're using gradle

Comment: @androidpotato7 yes you right I never thought of activities.

Comment: @Shine And in what circumstances do I need to set different settings (multiple apk) for my module? As Play Store will only allow 1 apk to be uploaded anyway.

Comment: @Halim Play Store allows far more than a single .apk :) read http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html