# Android Gradle Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, android-tv, leanback

I use the leanback library to develop for Android TV. My app declare the min API to 16 however the leanback as a minimum API of 16.
So as the documentation says I declared this in my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.mypackage.package">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback" />
```

However I still have the error :

Error:(6, 5) Execution failed for task ':app:processAdhocProdManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 17 declared in library /thepathtotheapp/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/leanback-v17/22.2.0/AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback" to force usage

in the Manifest merger report I can see :

```
MERGED from io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.0.2:7:5
    android:targetSdkVersion
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
    android:minSdkVersion
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
    tools:overrideLibrary
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:21:15
    tools:ignore
        ADDED from com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.4-RC1:14:9
application
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:23:5
```

So it look like it's adding the tools:overrideLibrary but it still fail.

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Well, the point behind `tools:overrideLibrary` is for you to then supply a replacement value: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:overrideLibrary-marker I don't see where you are doing that.

Comment: It's specified in my build.gradle file, I remove it from the build.gradle file and I specified : <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="16" tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback"/>  directly in the AndroidManifest But I still have the exact same error.

Comment: Hmmmm... I haven't used `tools:overrideLibrary` yet, and so I was hoping that perhaps putting the values in `<uses-sdk>` would help. You could try switching from `tools:overrideLibrary="..."` to `tools:node="replace"`, which in theory should replace all lower-priority instances of `<uses-sdk>` with yours. I have used `tools:node="replace"`, but not on `<uses-sdk>`.

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately : uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute . So I tried with "merge" as well instead of "replace" but still the same issue than before.

Comment: Well, my only other idea is that the error message is wrong and the library's package name is something else. But [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27310430/115145) looks like it has that value, and 65 people think it helped. Perhaps something changed/broke since December?

Comment: It's my only library with a minSdkVersion at 17 and the package name seems correct. So either something changed/broke or I do something wrong ... thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was coming from Mixpanel library, Mixpanel define its AndroidManifest with this tag :

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"
        tools:ignore="GradleOverrides" />
```

So I end up giving up on Mixpanel, I prefer give up on them than 10% of our users.

Comment: Having the same issue, but looks like mixpanel has some updates to fix this? https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/releases

Comment: Apparently yes, you should update and give it a try. I don't use Mixpanel anymore...

Comment: I can confirm that their update 4.8.0 fixed merging conflicts.