# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android

When I try to rebuild project, android studio gives the error:

`Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'`

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I tried all solutions provided for similar problems like this one:
[Android Gradle Manifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062893/android-gradle-manifest-merger-failed)

Following is app level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "io.tnine.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="io.tnine.myapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"/>

    <activity android:name=".fragment_console"></activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

What changes should I make?

**edit:**
project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I don't see an obvious error, but just for debugging purposes I'd try switching to `minSdkVersion 23 targetSdkVersion 23` from ` minSdkVersion 18 targetSdkVersion 22`  to see if that has any impact.

Comment: Also, can you add your 'project build.gradle' ?

Comment: @mawalker I have added the project build.gradle.

Comment: This issue occurs when issue in the manifest file tags. Please check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39509659/2732632

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing this tag:

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

because I had specified the API key in another tag below. It was not a problem of build.gradle

Comment: I had this error, solved it by checking the minSdk of all the libraries I had imported to make sure it was the same as my minSdk and sure enough one of them was higher than mine, changed my minSdk. Hope this helps with others

Answer (score 0):

Check all Resource files in **values** [color,string,dimen,style,etc], check is there any **undesirable attribute name** is present which should **not be present** in that file.
Do Correction in attribute name. 
clean the project.