# Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

So, I am a beginner into Android and Java. I just began learning. While I was experimenting with *Intent* today, I incurred an error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

I found some solutions here and tried to implement them, but it did not work.

This is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rohan.petadoptionthing"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
package="com.example.rohan.petadoptionthing" >

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Second"
        />

    <activity android:name=".third"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>


</application>
```

This is my first week with coding, I am sorry if this is a really silly thing. I am really new to this and did not find any other place to ask. Sorry if I broke any rules

Comment: remove line <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/> in your menifest.xml file

Comment: For detailed information about the error you can check Gradle Console in Android Studio on the bottom right corner.

Comment: I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918418/9180782) will be useful.

Comment: I got the same error.But solved it by keeping the same minimum SDK in project and library.

Comment: https://youtu.be/K88WaSm3q8Y "Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors in Android Studio"?

Comment: On your Build.Gradle you may add this: "maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }" so remove this and sync your Gradle. To me, it worked.

Answer (score 1467, accepted):

**Open application manifest (`AndroidManifest.xml`) and click on `Merged Manifest` tab on bottom of your edit pane.** Check the image below:

[image]

From image you can see **Error** in the right column, try to solve the error. It may help some one with the same problem. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts).

Also, once you found the error and if you get that error from external library that you are using, You have to let compiler to ignore the attribute from the external library.
//add this attribute in application tag in the manifest

```
   tools:replace="android:allowBackup" 
                                                                                                                                          
   //Add this in the manifest tag at the top

   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: in my case I scrolled it a bit  down to see the errors

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any "Merged Manifest" tab in Android Studio 3.5.2.

Comment: @FractalBob I am running 3.5.2 and see the 'Merged Manifest' tab..perhaps you have some other error occurring before manifests are merged.

Comment: @sonyisda1 Are you running in a Linux environment? I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @FractalBob Win10 Pro 1903

Comment: Don't forget to see the **manifest of the main app**, not the module's manifest)

Comment: adding `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` didn't solve my problem and Merge Error only showed up after putting that line thus I can't determine the cause of error

Comment: is it possible to allow backup of all modules? because if we replace it then parent modules/dependencies will lose their functionality of backup.

Comment: I don't see any "Error:" in the Merged Manifest tab, yet I still get the merger failed with 1 error.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I just updated junit dependency from 1.1.3 or later one and its worked.
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"

Comment: Bless you dear @Yosidroid

Comment: It does NOT show any errors for me even when scrolling down. But building the project doesn't work. I'm getting the "Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors" error.

Answer (score 125):

Remove  `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>` from your mainfest file. As you have already defined it as:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So, Manifest  file showing ambiguity.

Comment: It's too bad that this is the accepted answer, when it only fixes Rowen's code but is entirely unhelpful for anyone else. The answer by CLIFFORD actually shows you how to "see logs" as the error message suggests.

Comment: It work very well only check and remove any duplicate entry in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 73):

**For me THIS works -**

Finding Merging Errors in `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image]

Click on Merged Manifest in `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image]

You can view manifest merging error in right column. It may help to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a generic fix for this problem.  This helps you find the real reason for any problem regarding this.

Answer (score 66):

I was also facing same issues, and after lot of research found the solution:

> 1. Your min sdk version should be same as of the modules you are using eg: your module min sdk version is 14 and your app min sdk version is 9 It should be same.
> 2. If build version of your app and modules not same. Again it should same
>      ** In short, your app `build.gradle` file and manifest should have same configurations**
> 3. There's no duplicacy like same permissions added in manifest file twice, same activity mention twice.
> 4. If you have delete any activity from your project, delete it from your manifest file as well.
> 5. Sometimes its because of label, icon etc tag of manifest file:
>
> a) Add the `xmlns:tools` line in the manifest tag.
>
> b) Add `tools:replace=` or `tools:ignore=` in the application tag.

Example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.slinfy.ikharelimiteduk"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

  <application
      tools:replace="icon, label"
      android:label="myApp"
      android:name="com.example.MyApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
  </application>

</manifest>
```

> 6. If two dependencies are of not same version
>      example: you are using dependency for appcompat v7:26.0.0 and for facebook  com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)
>      facebook uses cardview of version com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1 and appcompat v7:26.0.0 uses cardview of version v7:26.0.0, So there is discripancy in two libraries and thus give error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
>       is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.

So by using appcompat of version 25.3.1, We can avoid this error

By considering above points in mind, you will get rid of this irritating issue.
You can check my blog too
https://wordpress.com/post/dhingrakimmi.wordpress.com/23

Comment: in my case it was due to theme of module I added
so I used as tools:replace"icon,label,theme"

Comment: in my case it was due to theme of module I added so I used as tools:replace"icon,label,theme"  and  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools". thanks @O'one

Comment: This is the most valuable answer for this question!

Answer (score 21):

Just add below code in your project Manifest application tag...

```
<application
        tools:node="replace">
```

Comment: worked in my case thanks

Comment: remember to add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`  namespace declaration in the manifest tag

Answer (score 18):

If your project targeted Android 12 then
Add this in all `<activity>` tags with `<intent-filter>`

```
android:exported="true/false"
```

Comment: What if all activities already have the exported tag?

Comment: This is likely correct, but look at the accepted answer for an explanation

Answer (score 15):

In addition to available solutions, please check this also.
If you have set `android:allowBackup="false"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` then there may be a conflict for `android:allowBackup="true"` in other dependencies.

**Solution**
As suggested by @CLIFFORD P Y, switch to `Merged Manifest` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Android Studio will suggest to add `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` in `<application />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same problem and I've just added one line in my manifest.xml and it worked for me.

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup,icon,theme,label,name">
```

> add this line under

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemecustom"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup,icon,theme,label">
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: thank you so much! I was facing this issue in a very specific scenario caused by Zendesk support page, when clicking on "attach file". Tried so many answers from different questions and only your comment helped!

Comment: @Natalie I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 11):

I solved this with **Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX**

GL

Answer (score 10):

solution for me was like this:

1- open manifest

2-On top right , check highlighted problems like below:
[image]

3-click on problems icon in red. this will open problems tab like below.
[image: problems tab]

4- solve them one by one

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing this error. In the build log the last line was "Failed to compile values file".

So if you're facing the same issue, then just adding the following line in the gradle.properties file will most probably fix the issue.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I mean it fixed `Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors in Android Studio` error for me.

Comment: That did it for me. Thanks, Bucky!

Comment: In my case, gradle.properties had all lines repeated twice, that's why it was throwing this error. Actually, this happened during merging of two branches of my project, master has old codebase, and feature branch had new codebase.

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was showing an error because there was a redundancy in `<uses-permission>` element.
So, please check in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for the same.

**Android Studio version is 3.0.1**

**Operating System is Windows 7**

Here is the screenshot for reference.

[image: Screen-shot which shows redundancy in manifest file.]

Comment: While this was posted before @CLIFFORD-P-Y's answer, finding merging errors via the Merged Manifest view will catch this particular redundant error.

Answer (score 7):

Usually occurs when you have errors in your manifest.Open AndroidManifest.xml .Click on the merged manifest tab.The errors can be seen there .Also include suggestions mentioned there.When I had a similar problem while importing com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng ,it suggested me to include tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.maps" in the application tag and the build was successful.

Answer (score 3):

My case i have fixed it by

> build.gradle(Module:app)

```
defaultConfig {
----------
multiDexEnabled true
}
dependencies {
    ...........
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    }
```

This answer releted to OnSignal push notification

Answer (score 2):

If after you add a **Android Library Module** and you get this error.
You can fix it by simple remove the `android:label="@string/app_name"` from the `AndroidManifest.xml` of your **Android Library Module**

Answer (score 2):

The minium sdk version should be same as of the modules/lib you are using 
For example: Your module min sdk version is 26 and your app min sdk version is 21 It should be same.

Answer (score 2):

I see the answers and they are complete and useful. Anyway, if you are completing the [Jetpack Compose Testing codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-navigation#6) and you find this error in late 2021, the solution is not the accepted answer, you need to downgrade your target sdk version to 30.

In app/build.gradle, replace:

```
targetSdkVersion 31
```

with:

```
targetSdkVersion 30
```

And run the Android Tests again

Answer (score 2):

in my case I was using multi models on firebase vision Dependencies in manifest file's meta-data tag, so I mixed them in one value parameter and it did solve my problem.here is how :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
    android:value="ocr,langid"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way I did and it worked successfully is by adding android:exported="true" as follows,

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ...
        android:exported="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   - At application, add `tools:replace="android:icon, android:theme` and
   - At the Manifest root, add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools`
2. In `build.gradle`:

   - At root, add `useOldManifestMerger true`

Answer (score 1):

for the past few days I was also going through the same issue. But after, a lot of research I finally found a solution for this.

 In order to solve this issue, what you need to do is:

 1. Check if your project's **build.gradle** file and the module's **build.gradle** file contain same versions of all dependencies.

 2. Make sure, your project's **compileSdkVersion**, **buildToolsVersion**, **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** matches the one in the **modules** or **libraries** that you have added into the project.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.appname"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 22
    versionName "2.0.3"

}
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the `FirebaseUI Library` along with the `Facebook SDK Library`, which was causing me the issue.

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.4'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

And from [here][1], I got rid of this issue.

With the `latest update` of **FirebaseUI library**, previous version of Facebook SDK is also a part of it.

If you are using the **both** the libraries, please **remove the Facebook SDK Library**.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/230

**UPDATE**

From the `Android Studio 3.0` and the later versions, `app.gradle` file is required to use `implementation` or `api` instead of `compile` for adding the dependencies to the app.

Comment: Its due to Facebook Ads SDK. I just update gradle and build tools version and all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Open your gradle console, then you see gradle suggest you to add the particular line (Like: tools:replace="android:allowBackup" or tools:replace="android:label" etc). Add that line into your manifest file under  tag and sync gradle, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happened for leaving some empty **intent-filter** inside the **Activity** tag

```
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>

            </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

So just removing them solved the problem.

```
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following hack works:

1. Add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` line in the
       manifest tag
2. Add
       `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme,android:allowBackup,label,name"`
       in the application tag

Comment: work for me Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you don't have proper statements at the Manifest root such:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.test">
```

So you should remove additional texts in it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved it by updating the **classpath** in build.gradle (Project) file to the latest version.

It was like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}
```

After updating to the latest version:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
}
```

Everything worked fine! Hope this helps someone if all the above answers don't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie to Android Studio, in my case, I had moved an existing project from Eclipse to Android Studio and found that there was a duplicate definition of an activity within my Manifest.xml that hadn't been picked up by Eclipse was shown as a Gradle error.

I found this by going to the Gradle Console (bottom right of the screen).

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me twice when I refractor (Rename with SHIFT + F6) the name of a field in our files and it asks you to change it everywhere and we without paying attention change the name everywhere.
For example, if you have a variable name "id" in your Java class and you rename it with SHIFT + F6. If you don't pay attention to the next dialog which will ask you wherever else it is going to change the id and you tick check all it will change all the id in your layout files from the new value.

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple error only occur when you define any activity call two time in mainifest.xml file Example like

```
<activity android:name="com.futuretech.mpboardexam.Game" ></activity>

//and launcher also------like that



//solution:use only one
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the end of your app module build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.0'
        }
    }
}}
```

[from this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45025597/5102893)

Answer (score 0):

Supplement the answer Phan Van Linh. I deleted these lines:

```
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="name"
```

Answer (score 0):

i sloved this problem by removing below line from AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just migrate to Androidx as shown above and then set teh minimum sdk version to 26...with no doubts this works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using some annotations from jetbrains library. I removed those annotations and dependencies and it worked fine.

So please check the libraries in android code and dependencies carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple [`manifestPlaceholder`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables) items in your `build.gradle` file, you must add them as array elements, instead of separate items.

For example, this will cause a build error or compile error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors":

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [myKey1: "myValue1"]
        manifestPlaceholders = [myKey2: "myValue2"] // Error!
    }
}
```

This will fix the error:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [myKey1: "myValue1", myKey2: "myValue2"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the new Material library with the legacy Support Library.

You have to migrate `android.support` to `androidx` in order to use `com.google.android.material`.

If you are using android studio v 3.2 or above, simply

> go to refactor ---> MIGRATE TO ANDROID X.

Do make a backup of your project.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing CLIFFORD's answer to see the error, what helped me to solve this issue was renaming 'android:namex' to 'android:name' in the intent-filter action tag. In case if the same solution helps someone else .

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:namex="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird encounter with this problem. when renaming variable `name` to `user_name`, I mistakenly rename all of the name to `user_name` for the project. So my xml tag `<color name:"">` became `<color user_name:"">` same goes for string, style, manifest too. But when I check merged manifest, it showed nothing, because I had only one manifest, nothing to find.

So, check if you have any malformed xml file or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my application tag includes:

```
 <application
    android:name=".common.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:extractNativeLibs="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

I resolved this issue my adding new param as android:appComponentFactory=""

So my final application tag becomes:

```
<application
    android:name=".common.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:extractNativeLibs="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:appComponentFactory="">
```

I encountered above issue when I tired using firebase-auth latest version as "19.3.1". Whereas in my project I was already using firebase but version was "16.0.6".

Answer (score 0):

check if you've any duplicate activity declared in the manifest. That was my mistake for this error and problem solved, after deleting the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

For all of you that have the same problem but when you merge the manifest and ***there's no error at all*** this solution worked for me without edit your "Manifest" file and changed any configuration, delete this, delete that ect.

1. Open your "settings.gradle" file.
2. Add this code "**gradlePluginPortal()**".

- If your start a new project the code automatically might be there if you are using the updated Android Studio but you need to add once more, like code below:

  ```
    pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}
    }
  ```

and put the code "***gridlePluginCentral()***" once more.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

In my case problems like this happened usually when we use the github user libraries and used it for layout files or as "imports" in java files. It's always a good idea to keep your Android Studio up-to-date and leave the old version as there are usually changes to configuration, libraries and other supporting files. And it's best to avoid using libraries from github users, preferably using libraries from Google.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the Thumbs.db file that was causing the Manifest merge error, I just had to delete that file and it worked.

if you hit this button on android studio :

[image: Expand all folders]

Under mipmap you will see a file called Thumbs.db, remove that rebuild APK
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to update this dependecy from build.gradle:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

to

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple Answer Cross Check :

You might be defined Same Activity multiple times in the manifest.xml file.

OR

Activity or service or receiver you have defined in the manifest.xml file which is not in your project structure.

Comment: Please do not use code blocks for non-code content. Your answer does not contain code so it should not be indented.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this by removing `android:replace` tag