# How can i add dependencies in Android Astudio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want add this dependencies  `compile 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'` into my Android studio Project.
When add this into dependencies and click on Sync show me this error :

```
Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0
<a href="openFile:G:/Android/Projects/1-MapTutorial/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

**build.gradle codes:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohammadn.a1_maptutorial"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'

    compile 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'
}
```

How can I fix it and add this library into my dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your project: build.gradle file to this

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}
```

Comment: When add this line and sync show me this error, please see this email : https://s13.postimg.org/6fmeq9k7b/image.png

Comment: @AngelF you need to change your `minSdkVersion 14` to `minSdkVersion 16`. Let me know if problem still persists.

Answer (score 2):

Add support **jitpact repository** in root `build.gradle` at the end of repositories:

```
    allprojects {
   repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}
```

Read official guideline about **[DrawRouteMaps .](https://github.com/ar-android/DrawRouteMaps/blob/master/README.md)**

Comment: When add this line and sync show me this error, please see this email : https://s13.postimg.org/6fmeq9k7b/image.png

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following lines to **project/build.gradle** (not app/build.gradle)

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'
```

Comment: When add this line and sync show me this error, please see this email : https://s13.postimg.org/6fmeq9k7b/image.png

Comment: Try clean & build

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842955/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-in-android-studio.

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion? You need to change it to 16
as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842955/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-in-android-studio

Comment: See minSdkVersion here on https://github.com/ar-android/DrawRouteMaps/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to add the Maven Repository in your project:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}
```

And then, add dependencies in `build.gradle` module app :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: When add this line and sync show me this error, please see this email : https://s13.postimg.org/6fmeq9k7b/image.png

Comment: try  to use build  -> rebuild project

Comment: you added the   maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in your build.gradle project file or module file?

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion? You need to change it to 16

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above comments you can add dependencies in file->project structure-> add->+(plus sign)->add library