# when I add compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1' to gradle file fails build

Tags: android

I want to implement `Searchable Spinner`, But When I add `compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'` to gradle file the build get failed. I dont know how to overcome this. The dependency code is below.

```
   dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
     //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
     compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
     compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
     compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
     compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
   }
```

Error is

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>            Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842955/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-in-android-studio)

Comment: duplicate found compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'

Comment: `compile` is depreciated use `implementation` and remove duplicate play service

Comment: Removed compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0' but still errors.thanks for help

Comment: share your gradle

Answer (score 0):

You have added the dependency multiple times

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

Remove one of those

Answer (score 0):

You try to sync `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'` dependency two times in your gradle. This is the reason for the issue.