# How to set a different AndroidManifest.xml only for run tests

Tags: android, gradle

I have a library with the most simple manifest possible

`<manifest package="com.xxx.xxx.android" />`

But this library needs to get two metadata values from Android Manifest to work properly, so to run my tests I added to `src/test/AndroidManifest.xml` the following code:

```
<manifest package="com.xxx.xxx.android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="var1"
            android:value="value1"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="var2"
            android:value="value2"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As I've read from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) I have to set the new `AndroidManifest.xml` path in `gradle`. I'm trying to do this way:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        String sharedTestDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'
        String testManifest = 'src/test/AndroidManifest.xml'
        test {
            java.srcDir sharedTestDir
            manifest.srcFile testManifest
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDir sharedTestDir
            manifest.srcFile testManifest
        }
    }

    testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources true
}
```

But it doesn't work and I'm not able to get the metadata in my tests. It only works if I set the `manifest.srcFile` for `main`, instead of `test` and/or `androidTest`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` in combination with `testBuildType "debug"`.

Comment: If I do this it works, but I start to get an error when trying to compile a sample using the library about `Manifest merge failing`. Do I do add something more in Manifest?

Comment: @VictorLaerte this should ordinary work barely based upon two alternate `AndroidManifest.xml`... could only imagine, that the path changes in `build.gradle` might mess up the default behavior. is there maybe a more detailed error message, which tells why it fails to merge?

Comment: I believe it's not wrongful. Doing the way you said the tests run successfully the only problem now is that my sample is not able to merge manifests. (Sample is also running debug mode)

Comment: the `LibManifest.xml` has no `application` tag - and the `SampleManifest.xml` does not open the `application` tag... which might explain the `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors`, see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

Comment: Sorry, the SampleManifest is opening the tag but I omited. But you right in LibManifest.xml. I'll try again

Comment: Doing the way you told me, looking to the documentation it says that application tag should be combined. All of them now have <application> but it's still not combining, can you see what I'm still doing wrong? :/

Comment: As you said looking to documentation and adding `tools:replace="android:value"` in my sample it works. This might be helpful to add in the original answer. This link also helped a lot https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023614/1965189