# Unable to publish app in Google Play store due to Declare sensitive permissions

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, publish

Recently I tried to publish an app in Google Play Store, but I am receiving the following error and my app is getting rejected every time.

[image]

I have removed all the SMS related permissions only basic permissions required are included in the app, and I have used some 3rd party libraries like PayPal, Payumoney. 
Please find the reference link below for more information regarding the updated Google Policy:

[Privacy, Security, and Deception](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/)

Comment: "I have removed all the SMS related permissions only basic permissions required are included in the app" -- make sure that you are checking your *merged* manifest, such as via the "Manifest Merger" tab in the manifest editor in Android Studio.

Comment: You need to understand which library is importing this permission. You can use `Merged Manifest` as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023614/2910520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot disable adding this permission by a dependency you can explicitly remove it from merged manifest like this:

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
tools:node="remove" />
```