# ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs | BUT NO ERRORS IN LOG

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I have the following error when I build my React Native app for Android (no problem on iOS).

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

This causes a real problem when I build in release mode (no problem with the app in debug) because it produces the following Manifest file for my release build:

***AndroidManifest.xml (in app/src/release/)***

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myAppName"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
</manifest>
```

I know there are plenty of questions about this but they don't really help in my case, because if I follow what is said in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023614/1432355) and go to `Merged Manfiest tab` on my `AndroidManifest.xml` file I don't see any errors:

[image]

**Below are my manfiest and gradle files**:

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.myApp">

<!-- Optional - Add the necessary permissions (Choose one of those) -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> <!-- Approximate location - If you want to use promptLocation for letting OneSignal know the user location. -->

<!-- End optional permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

<application
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

        <provider
            tools:replace="android:authorities"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                tools:replace="android:resource"
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

***build.gradle (Project: MyAppName)***

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

***build.gradle (Module: app)***

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.2, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myApp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 18
        versionName "0.6.3"
//        ndk {
//            abiFilters.clear()
//        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
// ...
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
//    splits {
//        abi {
//            enable true //enables the ABIs split mechanism
//            reset() //reset the list of ABIs to be included to an empty string
//            include 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
//            universalApk false
//        }
//    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'
        doNotStrip '*/mips/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/mips64/*.so'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    implementation project(':react-native-pdf')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.9" // From node_modules
    implementation('org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.0.0')
////    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

[image]

Comment: do you have other module in your app?

Comment: @PrachiSingh See update 1

Comment: make sure same dependencies have same versions in all modules gradle

Comment: @PrachiSingh The only difference is that I have `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.9"` and the modules `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"`. Setting them to the same version didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: @Moucheg I am using similar libraries and was having a conflict with rn-fetch-blob and image-picker.
Have you tried with provider's meta-data tag like this?
`<meta-data
                tools:replace="android:resource"
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />`

Comment: @ZassX Yes I've tried it but I have the same error. If I comment the rn-fetch-blob and image-picker dependencies I get this error in Merged Manifest tab: `Merging Errors: Warning provider#android.support.v4.content.FileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:29 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present app main manifest (this file), line 28 Warning meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@android:resource was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:35 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present app main manifest (this file), line 34`

Comment: @Moucheg just to test: leave dependencies commented and insert the meta-data tools:replace property. Still same error?

Comment: @ZassX Same error when commenting all dependencies

Comment: @Moucheg sorry man, I am out of ideas. I had same issue after updating Android Studio to new version, but had to make a crucial fix so temporarily solved by using older version of Studio to make a build which worked great. Ofc I am planning to resolve that so will keep an eye on this question and report back if I find anything. Good luck!

Comment: @ZassX I've found what was causing this error, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem wasn't really related to my code or gradle settings but to Android Studio itself.

I found out (with a lot of help) that in the Preferences (cmd + ,) there is a section called `Experimental` and in there there is an option called `Only sync the active variant` that was checked. Once I unchecked it there error went away.

I've filled an issue for this on `b.android.com`

[image]

Comment: @sam did you try to invalidate cache, clean project, restart AS ? What kind of errors do you have ?

Comment: error was same but I solve it  by updating all Gradle dependency