# "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" error

Tags: android, google-maps

"Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" error comes when I am creating a new maps activity in a new project.what should I do?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.The following lines are showing the error...
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment =(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add error logs?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842955/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-in-android-studio/35844350