# Reviving an old project but the manifest merger failed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am reviving an [old github repo](https://github.com/mitchtabian/Android-Instagram-Clone) of an instagram clone. The problem is, the manifest merger keeps failing.

I have tried updating, adding overrides, downgrading, removing then syncing then re-adding but nothing works.

I end up with the error:

```
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

I think it has something to do with firebase starting because one of the error is as follows

```
2019-08-21 19:24:34.311 32240-32240/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.facebook.orca cmp=com.facebook.orca/com.facebook.push.fcm.FcmInstanceIDListenerService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{c44bfd u0a246 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 proclist:32240, seq(0,0,0)}
```

Then again I get hundreds of other errors thrown at me upon running.

https://pastebin.com/TMsesZUX <- The full logcat

EDIT:

The error I get is:

```
Error: tools:replace specified at line:17 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified Android-Instagram-Clone-master-app main manifest (this file), line 16
```

Comment: Now that i'm reading through the Logcat, I see a lot of it is VR related. The repo didn't have any VR content in it as far as I could tell. I think it was calling on oculus and youtube VR and things like that. Im also seeing things like failed sensor readings maybe (?), and call on, not facebook.com, but acebook.com

Comment: `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors` simply means there is a conflict between the `attribute values` of your `project manifest` and another from `a referenced library`. To see your actual error follow [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023614/8043806)

Comment: @GiddyNaya - I get this error:

'Error: tools:replace specified at line:17 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified Android-Instagram-Clone-master-app main manifest (this file), line 16'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

All I had to do was add

```
android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
```

in the application tag in my AndroidManifest.xml