# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory after add Exoplayer 2.10.5

Tags: java, android, manifest-merging

In my project After add  Exoplayer 2.10.5 in my app.gradle file I get this error:

my gradle version is 3.5.2

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-171:19 to override.
```

And this is my app.gradle file :

```
 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    def lifecycle_version = '1.1.1'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:parent:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ayalma:ExpandableRecyclerView:0.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.github.samanzamani.persiandate:PersianDate:0.7'
    implementation 'com.xw.repo:bubbleseekbar:3.20'
    implementation 'com.yydcdut:sdlv:0.7.6'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.ms-square:etsyblur:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.pes.materialcolorpicker:library:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    //exo player :
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:$exoplayer_version"
    //multiDex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //zoomLayout
    implementation 'com.otaliastudios:zoomlayout:1.6.1'
    //Recorder
    implementation 'com.kailashdabhi:om-recorder:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.cleveroad:audiovisualization:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.sdsmdg.harjot:croller:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.github.razerdp:AnimatedPieView:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation project(path: ':persiancalendar')
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    //noinspection DuplicatePlatformClasses
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.11'
    }
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ir.sabapp.hefzquran">
    ...
    <application
        android:name=".ui.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,UnusedAttribute">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        //activities ,services , provider
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I use **tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"** in 
application tag in AndroidManifest file get this error :

```
 Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Whats the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842955/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-in-android-studio/35844350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-171:19 to override.

My Suggestion is - Move to [**`AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). You can migrate an existing project to ***AndroidX*** by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

Upgrade to

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'//3.6.3
```

Your **`dependencies`** will

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
 implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Comment: how can I fix this issue without migrate to **AndroidX** ?

Comment: @AliSheykhi Then don't use `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer`. Google recommend to switch AndroidX

Comment: @AliSheykhi Create a back up current project then switch to AndroidX

Comment: thank man worked ! but in some part of application some issue occured . like :  Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior

Comment: it will be `"com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"`