# Cause: duplicate entry: AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

I'm using a project downloaded from codecanyon.net, the project fails Gradle build with an error message. I tried reviewing other questions with a similar issue but none worked for me. Please anybody can help me fix this issue

> Cause: duplicate entry: AndroidManifest.xml

Below is the manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dreams.chat">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:name=".BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">

            <!--android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan">-->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ImageViewerActivity" />

        <service
            android:name=".services.FirebaseChatService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
                    tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <provider
            android:name=".utils.MyFileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/authority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ContactViewerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ChatDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SignInActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.CallScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.IncomingCallScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".services.FetchMyUsersService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.SinchService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ChooseSignInActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_sign_in"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ContactActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.PrivacyPolicyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.dreams.chat.status.glideProgressBar.OkHttpProgressGlideModule"
            android:value="GlideModule" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.StatusStoriesActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullScreenVideoTheme" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.CallListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan" />

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

and this is the excception detailed

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform timezago-1.1.8.aar (com.chootdev:timezago:1.1.8) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\JRAR\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.chootdev\timezago\1.1.8\a988a24719cbe07115df73a045aa251630cdb10\timezago-1.1.8.aar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\JRAR\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.chootdev\timezago\1.1.8\a988a24719cbe07115df73a045aa251630cdb10\timezago-1.1.8.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: ZipException, message: duplicate entry: AndroidManifest.xml. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           Please file a bug at http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with allowbackup and appComponentFactory. I found lead to my solution in this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842955/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-in-android-studio?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top), if logs and build is not providing enough details about the issue, do check merged manifest it show errors with suggestions.

Open **application manifest** (AndroidManifest.xml) and click on **Merged Manifest** (in bottom) see image below.

[image]