# "Cause: duplicate entry: AndroidManifest.xml" with a project having two manifest files

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-manifest

I get this error "Cause: duplicate entry: AndroidManifest.xml" every time I want to build my project.
I have cleaned and rebuild the project and it still gives this error.
my merged manifest has no errors.

This the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dream.chat">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
   

    <application
        android:name="com.dream.chat.BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.dream.chat.activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">

            <!--android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan">-->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dream.chat.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:permission="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            tools:replace="android:launchMode" />
        <activity android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.ImageViewerActivity" />

        <service
            android:name="com.dream.chat.services.FirebaseChatService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <service android:name="com.dream.chat.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.dream.chat.receivers.ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.dream.chat.utils.MyFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.ContactViewerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.ChatDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.SignInActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.CallScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.IncomingCallScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />

        <service
            android:name="com.dream.chat.services.FetchMyUsersService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.dream.chat.services.SinchService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.ChooseSignInActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_sign_in"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.ContactActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.PrivacyPolicyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.dream.chat.status.glideProgressBar.OkHttpProgressGlideModule"
            android:value="GlideModule" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.StatusStoriesActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullScreenVideoTheme" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dream.chat.activities.CallListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan" />

    </application>


</manifest>
```

This is the manifest file for the library /stories/AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rahuljanagouda.statusstories">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.rahuljanagouda.statusstories.glideProgressBar.OkHttpProgressGlideModule"
            android:value="GlideModule" />
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.rahuljanagouda.statusstories.StatusStoriesActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is the app/build.gradle

```
 //import com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
group = 'com.github.rahuljanagouda'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    google()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dream.chat"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '29.0.3'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
        exclude 'project.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        //exclude 'META-INF/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'sinch-android-rtc', version: '+', ext: 'aar')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.10.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.freemarker'
    }
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.eyalbira.loadingdots:loading-dots:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.1'
    implementation 'com.kbeanie:multipicker:1.6@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.vanniktech:emoji-google:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.mxn.soul:flowingdrawer-core:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    implementation project(path: ':statusstories')
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.daasuu:animateHorizontalProgressBar:0.2.4'
    implementation 'com.chootdev:timezago:1.1.8'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1'
    implementation files('libs/libphonenumber-4.1.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    // OkHttp3
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.1'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.95.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioConverter:0.0.8'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.95.1'
    implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
}
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
    options.addStringOption('charSet', 'UTF-8')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where Status can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.4.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place Status application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { name 'glide-snapshot'; url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626916/cause-duplicate-entry-androidmanifest-xml

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was, I forgot to delete the **.iml** file in the library folder, I deleted the file and the error was cleared.
Although am still facing some bugs in the code but not related to this question I have posted.