# Android Cause: duplicate entry: AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, build.gradle, androidx

My question is already asked by someone. But could not find the solution in that.Same error and same project like in these two links

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551877/cause-duplicate-entry-androidmanifest-xml-with-a-project-having-two-manifest)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626916/cause-duplicate-entry-androidmanifest-xml)

None of above links questions not answered properly.For me, It was working first. I migrated to androidx then got this error. Can someone help me to solve issue and how duplicated file created ?

Manifest 1 :
Already added in those two links.

Manifest 2 : Another module Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rahuljanagouda.statusstories">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label=
        "@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
   >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.rahuljanagouda.statusstories.glideProgressBar.OkHttpProgressGlideModule"
        android:value="GlideModule" />
    <activity android:exported="true" 
 android:name="com.rahuljanagouda.statusstories.StatusStoriesActivity" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
//apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group = 'com.github.rahuljanagouda'
version = '1.0.0'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

   }

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }

 }

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
// Glide v3 (stable)
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.9.0-SNAPSHOT'
// OkHttp3
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
}
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
options.addStringOption('charSet', 'UTF-8')
 }
```

Comment: Did you check merged manifest? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: No errors or warnings...

Answer (score 0):

Try to update all the libraries to latest version and also check your lib folder for the project. Delete the files from that folder if exist any .

Comment: libphonenumber-4.1 and sinch-android-rtc-3.17.4  if i remove new error                         Error : Could not find any matches for :sinch-android-rtc:+ as no versions of :sinch-android-rtc