# stripe version upto 16.7.1 is working on android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am trying to upgrade the stripe version to 16.9.0 from 12.6.1 in my android project. I had to do that upgrade due to google playstore submission not working for 12.6.1 and requesting to upgrade to 16.9.0. But when I try to build the project with 16.9.0 it's always get failed. It's working only up to 16.7.1. When I tried a version upper than that it says `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [com.stripe:stripe-android:16.8.0] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-54`. How can I get rid from this issue?

Comment: You need to provide clearer details like your gradle file and your Manifest file. Please also refer to this SO answer for how you can see a more detailed error message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023614/10654456

Answer (score 0):

Once I changed the gradle version to `3.5.4` from `3.5.3`, it works.