# Flutter build apk failured casue to AndroidManifest.xml path incorrect

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I'm building multiple apks for my flutter project.
what I do:

```
// Add these config to android/app/build.gradle
android {
  .
  .
  .
  splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}
```

Then, run commond line in terminal:

```
~/Path/project/ $ flutter build apk
```

but the error occurred:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mpProcessReleaseManifest'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/user/Path/project/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 57s
```

my flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale en-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

What I tried:
I create a new sample flutter project to test, it's successed.
I compared the AndroidManifest.xml path to test project, I find that in the test project, this file's path is:

```
/project_test/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/universal/AndroidManifest.xml 
/project_test/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/arm64-v8a/AndroidManifest.xml 
/project_test/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/armeabi-v7a/AndroidManifest.xml
```

So I guess that the reason is gradle load this file from android directory but not build, but I don't how to resolve. Someone have same issue?

More info, hope to help:
In project/android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69167593/11647620

Comment: Try this, Add to android/gradle.properties:    `android.enableJetifier=true`
`android.useAndroidX=true`

Comment: This two property existed.

Comment: @vinsent: Why you don't use `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` ?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I tried to set android:exported="true" and android:exported="false" respectively, but error no change.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I tried, no effect. And via the test_project, you can ignore this parameter when you add ` splits` config in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Just check your manifest file on the current directory

```
- project file
 - android
  - app
   - src
    - main
     - AndroidManifest.xml
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I checked it, it is there.