# How can I resolve "Manifest Merger" error in android-studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest

Am trying to build an application in android and I get this error "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs". How can I fix it?

I tried to to manipulate the androidmanifest.xml file. But then the error persists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35842955/7874746

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842955/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-in-android-studio)