# Error in Android Studio: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android-studio

Screenshot of Android Studio

[image: 1]

How do I resolve the an error in Android Studio as below: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs.

I have attached an Image with my question please see it once and Help me resolve my error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379187/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors If so, delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle files. I would suggest you to create new project and copy content in gradle to existing project and add required dependencies. Error is usually caused by incompatible version of java. Download latest Android studio and set jdk to java 17.

[Check this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build)