# Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

Tags: android

am purchased app(beetle game) from internet to edit on it .. but when i run app 
this msg appears to me

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library /Users/omar/Downloads/BeetleGame1/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/7.5.0/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all" to force usage
```

build.grade(project:beetlegame1)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

build.grade(module:app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.game"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

build.grade(module:google-play-services-lib)

```
    configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('google-play-services_lib.jar'))
```

i can attach the link to download app game which i have .. to see it :)

Comment: You need to add version number at the end in com.google.android.gms:play-services:X.X+

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27310430/717267

Answer (score 24):

The imported library google play services has a minsdk specified as 9 whereas you seem to be targeting much lower versions. To override it you need to add `tools:overrideLibrary` with the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml` file which will ignore the library specified minSDK version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your package name">

       <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all"/>
       --------------------------------
       --------------------------------
 </manifest>
```

> **tools:overrideLibrary marker**
>
> A special marker that can only be used with uses-sdk declaration to
>   override importing a library which minimum SDK version is more recent
>   than that application's minimum SDK version. Without such a marker,
>   the manifest merger will fail. The marker will allow users to select
>   which libraries can be imported ignoring the minimum SDK version.

Comment: same error,, but when i use this code <uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />
he told me to merge it in one element ,, when i made it ... (Error:(6, 5) uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute)

(Error:(6, 5) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute)

Comment: but the old error disappeared ,, and this new one :D

Comment: Just remove the tools:node="replace" line..I have corrected in my answer too

Comment: I have add the line and still having problem

Comment: @Renges Also often inserting one library is not enough, you should specify a set of such libraries like     <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="
            com.google.android.gms.maps,
            com.google.android.gms,
            com.google.android.gms.location
        " />

Answer (score 15):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22"
    tools:overrideLibrary="
    com.google.android.gms.all,
    com.google.android.gms.ads,
    com.google.android.gms.auth,
    com.google.android.gms.base,
    com.google.android.gms.measurement,
    com.google.android.gms,
    com.google.android.gms.analytics,
    com.google.android.gms.appindexing,
    com.google.android.gms.appinvite,
    com.google.android.gms.appstate,
    com.google.android.gms.cast,
    com.google.android.gms.drive,
    com.google.android.gms.fitness,
    com.google.android.gms.location,
    com.google.android.gms.maps,
    com.google.android.gms.games,
    com.google.android.gms.gcm,
    com.google.android.gms.identity,
    com.google.android.gms.nearby,
    com.google.android.gms.panorama,
    com.google.android.gms.plus,
    com.google.android.gms.safetynet,
    com.google.android.gms.wallet,
    com.google.android.gms.wearable" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because you do not declare a `minSdkVersion` in your `app`'s `build.gradle` file:

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.game"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
    }
}
```

Comment: 'A big error' is not descriptive enough to help you fix any remaining issues. I assume that this fix *did* remove the error this question was asking and instead started on whole new errors? If so, it would seem those would be appropriate for more questions.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

make minSdkVersion=9 like in the picture.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Open Android Studio -> Open Manifest File
>
> add   don't forget to include xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" too, before the  tag

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:maxSdkVersion="14"
    tools:overrideLibrary="x"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My code to override libraries and avoid the "suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 21,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23":

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.facephi.sdk.demo">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="
      com.company.licensing.lite;
      com.company.license_checker_component;
      com.company.some_component;" />
```

Very important to add: xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" in the AndroidManifest.