# Force tools:overrideLibrary Android

Tags: android, build, android-manifest, android-min-sdk

I am getting the following error trying to build my APK:

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0] /Users/jack/...
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook" to force usage
```

Even after I add the `tools:overrideLibrary` line to my `AndroidManifest`, I clean and build the project and receive the exact same failure message.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I have looked through some similar SO questions and none of the solutions are the fix I am looking for.

Comment: Provide you log and manifest part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a library that its minsdkversion is below your project's minsdkversion.

Just change your minsdkversion in your build.gradle file of your app to 15 and that will be ok ;)

There is another way which is not stable. Just force it to use by adding one line of code to your application manifest. See this link:

[How do I use tools:overrideLibrary in a build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095077/how-do-i-use-toolsoverridelibrary-in-a-build-gradle-file)

Comment: What if I intended for the minSdkVersion to be 14?

Comment: You cant use a library wich needs minsdkversion upper than your app. Its kinda that library rule. If the library is yours chanhe the mindsdkversion of the library. What is the library ?

Comment: It's the Facebook Parse library. Unfortunately I can't mess with the minSdkVersion for that :/

Comment: There is another way which is not stable. Just force it to use by adding one line of code to your application manifest. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095077/how-do-i-use-toolsoverridelibrary-in-a-build-gradle-file