# compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.0' gradle build error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am creating a chat based app in this app its require AuthUI i used

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.0'
```

when i clicked on sync its show me this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.0] C:\Users\Pankaj.android\build-cache\b6b125d590bd1b7420872b94c0da26aebbc55221\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui.auth" to force usage

build.gradle(app)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

build.gradle(project)

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
repositories {

    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Do whatever is said in the error message

Comment: <manifest 
    ... >
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>
    ...
</manifest>

Comment: @ToasterI don't understand what you want to say I am a beginner in this please understood me ,Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095077/how-do-i-use-toolsoverridelibrary-in-a-build-gradle-file

Comment: `tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui.auth" `

Comment: That's an extremely old version of FirebaseUI.  Have you considered upgrading to the latest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

raise the minimum API level from `15` to `16` in the module's `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

`tools:overrideLibrary` is not really an option, because it will crash on devices with API level `15`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because FirebaseUI requires API 16 or above to run, while your app's `minSdkVersion` is set at 15. If Android Studio let you build like this, your app would just crash for users on API 15.

The comments suggest using the `tools:overrideLibrary` Manifest field, but I don't recommend doing this, because of the reasons described above. You'd have to implement your own authorization UI for API 15 users.

[According to Google](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/), 0.3% of active Android users are currently using API 15. This is only devices with the Play Store installed, but it's a pretty good representation of the total portion of Android users running API 15. If you're implementing FirebaseUI, it simply isn't worth it to make your own Auth UI for 0.3% of the total number of Android users.

The easiest and most sensible solution would probably be to just change your `minSdkVersion` to 16. You're already missing out on the other 0.3% of users on API 10-14. Another 0.3% is nothing.