# Unresolved reference: MasterKey

Tags: android, encryption, androidx

I am trying to follow examples given here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data

I have included the required libraries in my gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0"

// For Identity Credential APIs
implementation "androidx.security:security-identity-credential:1.0.0-alpha02"
```

And yet when I try to use the code:

```
val mainKey = MasterKey.Builder(applicationContext)
    .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
    .build()
```

I get unresolved reference: MasterKey error. Does the library have that class at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking advantage of a hook in Jie Heng's response…

The [MasterKey API](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/security/crypto/MasterKey) was added in the `androidx.security` package from the `1.1.0-alpha01` version of `security-crypto` (you can access the versions of this library [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.security/security-crypto)).

If you apply the [solution informed by Jie Heng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67614813/2578331), you will be successful.

But if the Android project you're working on supports Android API 23 (aka Android Marshmallow or just Android 6)…

something that should be accepted without problems, exactly as stated in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data). Documentation showing how to use the `EncryptedSharedPreferences` and `EncryptedFile` APIs…

if you go with `minSdkVersion` being `23`, then you'll notice that the project won't even compile.

That was my case!

The project I work on supports from Android API level 23.

So I [applied the following update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27310430/2578331) to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="...">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.security.identity.credential" />
...
```

And the project ran smoothly, including on Android API 23 (on AVD API 23).

**Note:** another option is to use the [MasterKeys API](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/security/crypto/MasterKeys) instead of `MasterKey`. But be aware that `MasterKeys` is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

Upgrade the library to latest version (1.1.0-alpha03 at the time of this writing)

```
implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03"
```

From the [release note](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security), `MasterKey` is added on Version 1.1.0-alpha01.

```
Version 1.1.0-alpha01
...
New MasterKey class provides more options for keys, also deprecating MasterKeys to support new features and versions of Android that do not have KeyGenParamSpec.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `val mainKey = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC)`.
MasterKey is only on alpha, so it seems that marking MasterKeys as deprecated was too early.